# Can't insert NSAttributedString into NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, nstextview

Previously I've been able to use the following code to place attributed text into an NSTextView field

```
[[self->content textStorage] appendAttributedString:contentString];
```

However, upon updating to the Xcode 6 Beta to develop for Yosemetie, what used to work now gives me this error:

```
2014-08-26 11:06:06.635 JaxWire[59482:1765389] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-08-26 11:06:06.636 JaxWire[59482:1765389] Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread.
```

and a whole much more globety gloop that I don't think has much use.

To give context as to how it works, a user enters text in a field, triggers a method called `GO` in the class `InterfaceManager` which then runs the following code to spawn a new thread `ProcessQuery` in the `AppDelegate` class, which is where I am attempting to change the content of NSTextView with an attributed string

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(processQuery:) toTarget:self withObject:query];
```

It's worth noting that this works if I use a standard string by executing `[self->content setString:@"String"];` but when it comes to using an attributed string, it doesn't work.

How would I go about fixing this problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are trying to modify the layout engine on a background thread. You need to do it on the main thread.

Comment: @Dima But this code used to work before with Xcode 5. Besides, I don't know how to push it to the main thread...

Comment: I'll write some sample code in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the string on the main thread instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
{
    [[self->content textStorage] appendAttributedString:contentString];
});
```

Comment: Careful. Without knowing the context of the surrounding code, you can't be sure that doing that asynchronously is safe. For example, what if `contentString` is a mutable attributed string and is mutated just after the original call to `-appendAttributedString:`? With your change, that mutation is in a race with the dispatch. Sadly, you also can't know that using `dispatch_sync()` would be safe, either, because it might deadlock. :(

Comment: Nah surrounding code wasn't super complex in terms of how things are synchronously or asynchronously, which means the code worked brilliantly! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

it has **nothing** at all to do with Xcode. You are explicitly asking for this to be done on a background thread by using `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector]`, and as has been pointed out in comments, this is not allowed. You have never been "allowed" to modify the UI from a background thread, but often you could do so without noticeable problems. Yosemite is likely just enforcing this more strictly than previous versions of OS X.

I suppose the reason it works with `setString:` is because `setString:` probably doesn't immediately call the layout engine and rather the next drawing pass on the main thread does that.

you either have to *not* detach `processQuery` to a background thread, or have `processQuery` call `appendAttributedString` on the main thread using something like:

```
[[self->content textStorage] performSelector:@selector(appendAttributedString:) withObject: contentString]
```

or using GCD `dispatch_async()` with the main thread's queue `dispatch_get_main_queue()`